# Can Joomla and Wordpress use same MySQL database?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I have a Joomla site installed at `example.com/fresh`. Now, I want to install WordPress. I am planning to install WordPress under subdirectory `information`; so my URL will be `example.com/information`.

Now, when I configure the WordPress installation, can I use the same MySQL database which is being used for Joomla site? I understand that using prefix allows this to work. Is this a good practical decision for a small site?

Comment: "small site" / "Joomla _and_ WordPress" ;) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use the same MySQL database which is being used for joomla site?

Of course. There is no technical reason why you can't. As long as there is no conflict in table names, which as you noted can be overcome with table prefixes, they can happily coincide.

> Is this a good practical decision for a small site?

Sure. This is quite common.

However, if you have the ability to separate the two you should. Both of those pieces of software have had their share of vulnerabilities, so if one is compromised now both are potentially comprised. By having separate databases for each you put a wall between the two and if one is compromised the other is kept safely separated (essentially firewalled).

Comment: One database per application is highly recommended as it does afford some limited security benefits but can make debugging performance issues much easier.  In terms of security, I find that attackers who can successfully get into a database usually can drop a PHP shell kit and simply read your configuration files to get passwords to other databases.